# Как нужно передавать пропсы?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, hook

Делаю реализацию пагинации списка через пользовательский хук. Функция `handleSetCurrentPage` получает корректный `number`, она его устанавливает `setCurrentPage(number)` как значение новой странички и вызывается новый рендер. Консольлог `setCurrentPage(number)` показал `undefined`. При этом если делать весь тот же код только в рамках одного файла( всё закинуть в `ListOfItems`) то работает отлично.

```
export const usePagination = (users = [], defaultPage = 1, amountPerPage = 10) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(defaultPage);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [amountOfPages, setAmountOfPages] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateUsers();
        updateAmountOfPages();
    }, []);

    const updateUsers = () => {
        const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * amountPerPage;
        const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - amountPerPage;
        const updatedUsers = users.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
        setCurrentUsers(updatedUsers);
    };

    const updateAmountOfPages = () => {
        const updatedAmount = Math.ceil(users.length / amountPerPage);
        setAmountOfPages(updatedAmount);
    };

    return {
        setCurrentPage,
        amountOfPages,
        currentUsers,
    };
};


export function ListOfItems() {
    const users = useSelector(state => state);
    const { setCurrentPage, currentUsers, amountOfPages } = usePagination(users);
    let {url} = useRouteMatch();

    let items = currentUsers.map(function (value, index) {
        return (
            <form key={index}>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                        <Link className="input-group-text" to={`${url}/${index}`}>
                            {value.name}, {index}
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {/*<form className="card">*/}
            {/*    <Search setSearch={setSearch} />*/}
            {/*</form>*/}
            <div>{items}</div>
            <div>
                <Pagination amountOfPages={amountOfPages} setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


const Pagination = ({amountOfPages, setCurrentPage}) => {
    const [pageNumbers, setPageNumbers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        calculatePageNumbers();
    }, [amountOfPages]);

    function calculatePageNumbers() {
        const updatedPageNumbers = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= amountOfPages; i++) {
            updatedPageNumbers.push(i);
        }
        setPageNumbers(updatedPageNumbers);
    }

    function handleSetCurrentPage(number) {
        console.log(number);
        return console.log(setCurrentPage(number));
    }

    return (
        <nav>
            <ul className="pagination">
                {pageNumbers.map(number => (
                    <li key={number} className="page-item">
                        <button
                            onClick={() => handleSetCurrentPage(number)}
                            type="button"
                            className="page-link"
                        >
                            {number}
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: Что по-вашему мнению должен вывести console.log(setCurrentPage(number)) ?

Comment: @Izzei- Саму функцию, никак не `undefined`, `undefined` значит что функции нет, что реакт не знает что ему рендерить. То есть вызов функции происходит, а её рендер нет

Comment: какую функцию? Вы же ее вызвали, как он вам ее вернет?

Comment: @Izzei- То есть `onClick` вызывает функцию которая возвращает `setCurrentPage`? Вызов функции которая вызывает перерендер?

Comment: onclick вызывает стрелочную функцию, которую вы передали, а она в свою очередь вызывает handleSetCurrentPage и только. функция на изменение состояния, которую вы получаете от useState всегда возращает undefined.

Comment: `useState всегда возращает undefined` ок спасибо, этого я не знал. Теперь понятно что этот консольлог не информативный, но `handleSetCurrentPage` получает норм `number`  почему он не устанавливается в `state`? Посмотрел доку реакта, "как вызывать функции из JSX", по доке код верный.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111515/discussion-between-d2207-and-izzei).

Comment: console.log currentPage после вызова setCurrentPage, что в себе содержит?

Comment: содержит новый number, то есть функция по клику работает нормально. Значит надо в useEffect закинуть эту функцию. Элементарно, как я до этого не додумался, меня честно говоря сильно сбивает тот факт что этот же код но в 1 файле работает нормально, как только логику вынес в отдельную функцию - не работает

Comment: Если вам нужно useEffect вызывать по измнению currentPage, то вам нужно в массив указать currentPage именно, а не функцию, с помощью который изменяете

Comment: низкий вам поклон со стула до линомеума!!!!!!!

Comment: Кланяться не нужно) Рад был помочь, удачи)

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        updateUsers();
        updateAmountOfPages();
    }, [currentPage]);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]